# iOS POST request parameters random crash when connecting to Zend server

Tags: ios, zend-framework, ios5, nsurlconnection

This question is related to this other one: [Zend getParameters not returning what is in url route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599606/zend-getparameters-not-returning-what-is-in-url-route)

The problem I'm facing is that, randomly, the Zend server does not get the parameters that are in the route, causing the login of my app crash. I.e., sometimes when printing the `getParams();` function I get the user email as following:

```
Array (
    [email] = user@email.com
    (...)
)
```

This works fine, but some other times I get this:

```
Array (
    [user@email.com] = 2.874983 //Longitude
    (...)
)
```

Causing the crash of the login action.

This could be a fault in the server side or in the client side. I've put an `NSLog` to print the `NSMutableURLRequest` each time the server gets called, and I've seen that the request url is always well formed. Maybe this is a coincidence, I don't know, but sometimes trying to solve this issue I've changed the request code and it was temporarily fixed. But then, after some requests, the error was back.

The following snippet represents the code I'm using to connect to the server:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self._url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                    timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSMutableString *values = nil;
if ( params ) {
    NSDictionary *parameters = params;
    values = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];        
    for ( NSString* key in parameters ) {
        NSMutableString *value = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        [value appendString:key];
        [value appendString:@"="];
        [value appendString:[self urlEncodeValue:[parameters valueForKey:key]]];
        [value appendString:@"&"];
        [values appendString:value];
    }
}
NSData *postData = [values dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLenght = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
if ( cookies ) {
    NSDictionary *cooks = cookies;
    for ( NSString* cookie in cooks) {
        NSMutableString *ck = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:cookie];
        [ck appendString:@"="];
        [ck appendString:[cooks valueForKey:cookie]];
        [theRequest addValue:ck forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
    }
}
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:self._method];
if ( values ) {
    [theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: postData];
    [theRequest setValue:postLenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
}
// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSLog(@"%@", theRequest);
NSURLConnection *theConnection =[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Another important thing is that the login sends both latitude and longitude values, and it seems that it's crashing when some of those values changes.

Comment: What exception are you seeing?  What does the crash look like (reason, stack trace)?

Comment: When the Zend server validates the parameters the application crashes because it cannot find the `[email]` parameter. This is happening when the parameters arrive in this way `[user@email.com] = 2.874983` instead `[email] = user@email.com`

Comment: I saw that in your question.  I can't help with the server return values but I might be able to give some advice about preventing a crash if you described the actual iOS error.

Comment: Well, there is no iOS error per se, I'm receiving the result of the Zend_Exception in my app correctly and displaying a login error message to the user. I think that maybe the problem comes from a wrong NSURLRequest in the iOS code...

Comment: Ah...sorry.  I saw the word 'crash' and thought you meant 'crash'.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem and I've posted the solution here: [Zend getParameters not returning what is in url route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599606/zend-getparameters-not-returning-what-is-in-url-route/12948859#12948859)

It was a `memcached` configuration problem, nothing to do with the iOS client application.